# resize .webp extension image using cwep

Tags: javascript, java

While resizing `.webp` file using cwebp, getting error

> Error! Could not process file originalImage.webp
> Error! Cannot
>   read input picture file 'originalImage.webp'

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [questions documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and feel free to adapt yours

Answer (score 0):

Getting the same error when first parameter is **.png** an second is **.webp**.
So i changed their places and it's worked.

```
 cwebp -o ancientnums.webp ancientnums.png
```

Workd fine, but i guess google have better instructions.
[This is](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/cwebp)